# How to invoke a key-down event to a Tkinter Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I forked a Github repository of a Python implementation of [2048](https://github.com/yangshun/2048-python) game and I wanted to add more features. I am new to Python and Tkinter and all the solutions I have found did not help yet.

The Game is displayed by a Tkinter Frame. A listener for key-down events is already bound. I want a separate Object to generate several key-down events to interact with the game (instead of the human user).

The `mainloop` is called within the Game constructor. I tried to call `event_generate` on the Game Object from another Object, but nothing happened. Just after I killed the application, I got the Exception `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed`.

I tried the same with a custom `Foo` event and generated a new event. The same error occurs.

The [Game class](https://github.com/yangshun/2048-python/blob/master/puzzle.py):

```
class GameGrid(Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.master.bind("<Key>", self.key_down)
    self.master.bind("<<Foo>>", doFoo)
    ...
    self.mainloop()
```

My approach:

```
gamegrid = GameGrid()
gamegrid.master.event_generate("<Key>", keycode=27, when="tail")
gamegrid.master.event_generate("<<Foo>>", when="tail")
```

I tried this with varying parameters.

Comment: Could you give us a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can better help you?

Comment: Why do you want to invoke the event rather than just calling the function that the event triggers? Just use `self.keydown()` whenever you want to emulate a keypress.

Comment: @DavidDuran I added the code :)

Comment: @Novel The same happens there. After initializing the Game, the Tkinter Frame starts the `mainloop`. All method calls after the `mainloop` are only executed after closing the Game, thus cannot interact with the game.

Comment: @Lando-L That has nothing to do with key binding. The `mainloop` is blocking, so any other loop you make has to be part of the mainloop or run in a separate thread.

Comment: @Novel I don't know how to call any function within the `mainloop`. Can you provide me with a simple code example?

Comment: @Lando-L what is your overall goal? To make a function part of the tkinter mainloop you would use the tkinter `after` method.

Comment: @Novel My overall goal is to implement a simple neural network to learn to play the 2048 game. The repository I forked is already split in two parts, the game logic and the UI. I use the game logic to train the NN and I want to test it using the UI. Thus I need to simulate key-down events depending on the current state of the game.

Comment: @Lando-L What's your github? I'll push an example.

Comment: @Novel That would be nice. My repo is [here](https://github.com/Lando-L/2048-python). The UI class is called [puzzle.py](https://github.com/Lando-L/2048-python/blob/master/puzzle.py), containing the Tkinter Frame.